# ICE Faces - sending filename param to bean from ice:outputResource

Tags: datatable, icefaces, param

I have acefaces datatable with file names, one on row and I'm trying to add a download button using ice:outputResource, but I fails in sending the filename to outputResourceBean.

My datatable looks like:

```
<h:form id="exportedFiles">
       <ace:dataTable value="#{exportBean.allFiles}" var="upload" 

                    <ace:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >
                            <h:outputText value="Název souboru"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{upload.name}"/>
                    </ace:column>

                    <ace:column>
                        <f:facet name="header" >
                            <h:outputText value="Dowload file"/>
                        </f:facet>      
                        <ice:outputResource id="downLink" 
                                            resource="#{outputResource.pdfResource}"
                                            attachment="true"
                                            label="Download PDF"
                                            type="button">
                        </ice:outputResource>
                    </ace:column>
                </ace:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

And my bean look like this:

```
public static final String PDF_NAME = "Download_PDF.pdf";
public static final Resource PDF_RESOURCE = new MyResource(PDF_NAME);
public String getPdfName() { return PDF_NAME; }
public Resource getPdfResource() { return PDF_RESOURCE; }
```

I can get the filename using #{upload.name} but I have no idea how to send it to bean when clicking the Download button...

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your list containing the files into a `ListDataModel`. That allows you to access the data of the current selected row index.

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ExportBean {

    private ListDataModel<MyResource> allFiles;

    public ListDataModel<MyResource> getAllFiles() {
        if (allFiles == null) {
            List<MyResource> files = new ArrayList<MyResource>();
            files.add(new MyResource("doc1.pdf"));
            files.add(new MyResource("doc2.pdf"));
            files.add(new MyResource("doc3.pdf"));
            files.add(new MyResource("doc4.pdf"));
            files.add(new MyResource("doc5.pdf"));
            allFiles = new ListDataModel<MyResource>(files);
        }
        return allFiles;
    }

    public String getPdfName() {
        // add the getResourceName method to MyResource
        return allFiles.getRowData().getResourceName();
    }

    public Resource getPdfResource() {
        return allFiles.getRowData();
    }
}
```

And the xhtml page would look like this:

```xhtml
<h:form id="exportedFiles">
    <ace:dataTable value="#{exportBean.allFiles}">
        <ace:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{exportBean.pdfName}" />
        </ace:column>
        <ace:column>
            <ice:outputResource resource="#{exportBean.pdfResource}" attachment="true" label="Download PDF" type="button" />
        </ace:column>
    </ace:dataTable>
</h:form>
```